# SCOM agent heartbeat failed on solaris 11.4

Tags: solaris, agent, heartbeat, scom

i am using Operations Manager 2016 for monitoring a host with Solaris 11.4 OS.
after several hours (24 h), host state is changed to gray and i get this text "The Run As account does not exist on the UNIX/Linux Server. " but Run As account is valid.
This problem is fixed each time by reset SCOM agent on host. I get this error over and over again.
also service log in /var/svc/log/application-management-omid:default.log is normal.
thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the solution to this problem.
In my case, this problem is due to the lack of a  lsass.so library in the system.
The problem was resolved after updating this library and modifying the PAM Configuration file.
thanks.